# Real time prediction using LSTM in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to construct a real time prediction system to predict a word from sign language gestures using an LSTM net. I understand that I can use the stateful LSTM model to do so. However, in a real time prediction, I would need to manually reset the states once my prediction is done am I right? For example, once I have predicted a word from the gesture of the user, I would need to reset the states of the network in order for me to predict the next word. Not resetting the state would result in poor prediction right? (I have not tested this out yet)

How do you suggest I handle this problem? Do I need an external signal (maybe a button press?) to indicate the end of a sequence prediction? Or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: It's hard to say because maybe the previous gesture might help in predicting a next one. Moreover - if you have a big dataset - a network might learn the end of a gesture on it's own and reset states using a forget gate.